# jquery mask works only one time after ajax content loaded

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Some content is displayed by ajax to be rendered in a div as a lightbox that is closed when user clicks outside (this content is deleted at this point):

Every time user clicks on the target div, some content goes to this controller:

controller:

```
def ajax_load
  // some code
end
```

And finally this js function is called from controller:

**ajax_load.js.erb**

```
<% if @variable %> // embedded variable
  $(target_div).html("<%= j render 'path' %>");

  $('.some_div').on('click', '#target_element', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("input#element_0").mask("00/00"); // works only once
    $("#element_1").prop('checked','checked'); // works
    $("#element_2").show(); // works       
  });

<% end %>
```

Inside this lightbox I have some inputs and this jquery mask function is called and it indeed works when I open this element once on the page, but if a close the lightbox and call it again it doesn't anymore, and the other lines of this click function keep working, like "jumping" the mask function.

If I try to make this mask to work directly from browser console after it had stop to work it don't change.

Obs: I also made some tests on the browser console:

After that lines of code above had already being loaded from the js file, the only way to get this to work on the browser console is changing a little from the jquery path:

```
$(".previous_div input#element_0").mask("00/00");
```

and to make it work again we need to change a little more:

```
$("body .previous_div input#element_0").mask("00/00");
```

Comment: Could it be that you have more than one element with id `element_0`?

Comment: Despite the behavior being like this, when I search on the source code I can't find.

Comment: I don't think the actual code has that id twice (since it works the first time), but you are rendering some html with an ajax call and I guess it's adding that element to the body. Instead of the code, check the DOM when your code does not work. I'm guessing your code is note getting deleted when the user closes the lightbox, double check that, your current hacky solution may work but you have repeated elements on your body that can give you headhaches later.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem in a way that I think is not the most recommendable.

Because of the behavior being like that I have duplicated id (and inspecting the source code it doesn't has it), I changed the id of the element and mask it again, and after that, works to me. Now I can close this lightbox and open again many times and have the input with the mask right there.

```
$("input#element_0").mask("00/00");
$("input#element_0").attr("id","element_0_masked");
$("input#element_0").mask("00/00");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but from retrivied ajax added this script and it's worked for me

```
<script> 
   $('input[name="txt-tel"]').mask('(000)-000-0000');
   $('input[name="txt-dni"]').mask('#');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the unmask() function before mask(), like this:

$("input#element_0").unmask();
$("input#element_0").mask("00/00");

It works for me.